# How to put content under the first record rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am on Rails 4. I have two resources: subarticles and articles. Subarticles are nested in articles like so:

```
  resources :articles do
    resources :subarticles do 
      member do 
        put "like" => "subarticles#upvote"
        put "dislike" => "subarticles#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

On the articles show page, I display all of the subarticles. However, I would like to place some of the article attributes ( specifically pictures and videos) directly under the first subarticle.

I am having trouble finding any documentation on doing so.

Also note that I have subarticles ordered by number of votes. So if one gets voted higher than the other, it will go to the top. But I want to keep the same pictures and videos right under the first subarticle.

Here is a simplified version of my Article show page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">

    <div class="well" style="background:white; height:230px">
      <%= @article.title.titleize %><br>
      <%= social_share_button_tag %>
    </div>

    <% @subarticles.each do |subarticle| %>
      <div class="well" style="background:white">
        <%= subarticle.rating %><br>
        <%= subarticle.whyrating %><br>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" style="margin-top:30px">

            <%= link_to like_article_subarticle_path(@article, subarticle), class: "like", method: :put do %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-right:5px">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Helpful
            </button><span class="badge" style="margin-right:10px"><%= subarticle.get_upvotes.size %></span>
            <% end %>

            <%= link_to dislike_article_subarticle_path(@article, subarticle), class: "like", method: :put do %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-right:5px">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Unhelpful
            </button><span class="badge"><%= subarticle.get_downvotes.size %></span>
            <% end %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="well" style="background:white; text-align:center">
      <h4>Pictures & Videos</h4><br>
      <%= image_tag @article.image1(:medium) %><br>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<%= @article.video1 %>"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Because of the `@subarticles.each do` it will push pictures and videos all the way to the bottom. What is the best way to show just the first subarticle, then pictures & videos, then the rest of the subarticles?

Let me know if I need to show any other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @subarticles.each_with_index do |subarticle, i| %>
   <div class="well" style="background:white">
   ....... // subarticle contents
   </div>

   <% if i==0 %>
   // put articles content here
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In that way after the first `subarticle` the **if** condition checks the loop index, as the loop index is currently 0, then it will first show the `subarticle` first content, then for index 0 it shows the `article` contents.

Comment: Thank you very much been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a flag for that:

```
<% first_one = false %>
<% @subarticles.each do |subarticle| %>
   <div class="well" style="background:white">
     ...
   </div>

  <% unless first_one %>
    // article contents here....
    <% first_one = true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```